# Entity Framework: Cascade delete works other way round than expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have 3 entities: `Address`, `Student` and `Faculty`. Here is the relationship diagram:

[image]

Entity Classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Faculty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Context` file, I'm defining defining the relationships and setting the cascade delete to true:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.Address)
        .WithOptional(a => a.Student)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Faculty>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.Address)
        .WithOptional(a => a.Faculty)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

My use case is that when I delete a `Student` or a `Faculty` object, I want the associated `Address` to be deleted as well. However, it works other way round.

Any thoughts/suggestions on this?

Comment: Right now your code requires an address to exist for a student or faculty, but an address does not require a student or faculty to exist.

Comment: @Kateract That's correct. What I mean to say is that, an address record can't have both student and faculty. It will have either of them.

Comment: @Dumbledore what happens when a teacher has a child or spouse living at the same address? Or when a teacher is also a student? :O

Comment: I'm not focusing on that scenario at the moment. For this question, let's assume that a teacher and a student are two different persons and they don't live at the same address.

Comment: Is it an option for you to use inheritance? I.e. make Student and Faculty derive from a base class?

Comment: Yes! Do you mean Person as a base class?

Comment: Yes. Then you can have one address linked to the base class, so a Student will never have a Faculty's address and vv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to move all of the Address columns into the Student/Faculty table.

Then to make EF happy with your object model, you use the ComplexType attribute on the Address class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

---

Part of the reason I say this is the "correct answer" is that you haven't addressed the problem of two students sharing the same address record. Nothing in your object model prevents it from happening, and if it does then what happens when you try to delete one student?

Comment: This isn't an answer

Answer (score 2):

The real issue is that you have not modeled what you are looking for correctly.  There is no semantic difference between your student and faculty tables.  Therefore, you are relationally incorrect in assuming that a migratory foreign key will suffice.  In other words, the master in your master detail tables is address.  Your model shows that there is a one to many relationship between address and faculty as well as one between address and student.  Therefore, the ONLY way a cascade delete will work is by first deleting the address.  In fact, I would probably add the type as a sub-table so that a person can have multiple roles with multiple addresses.

I would model it differently.  I would say PERSON(ID, NAME, TYPE) => 0,1 ADDRESS(ID, STREET).  In which case, if you delete a person (which can be either faculty or student), the corresponding address(es) will also be deleted.

This ably demonstrates the disconnect between OO and Relational.  Taking a purely OO approach to data storage can get a bit strange.

Comment: Thanks. However, PERSON(ID, NAME, TYPE) => 0,1 ADDRESS(ID, STREET) would mean that an `Address` may or may not exist for a `Person`, when it's supposed to be required.

Comment: I'm not sure how did you deduce that there is a one to many relationship between `Address` and `Faculty`. Could you please clarify on that? My relationship diagram shows 1 to 0..1.

Comment: The terminology is "one to many", but the "doesn't exist" is always implied.  Think of it as a master detail.  You don't HAVE to use cascade delete, but if you do, you cannot have the "master" (or the mandatory end of the 1...0) be the child in a cascade.  I'm not really sure how to explain how to fix the model other than to say that you have it set up backwards for cascade delete rules to work.  If you want the cascade to work, you have to implement PERSON 1 => 0,1 ADDRESS with the code ensuring that if you create a person that the address be implemented. Otherwise no cascade delete.

Comment: You could implement it as PERSON 1 => 1 ADDRESS, but you are locking yourself into a single address.  If that's the case, it's better to just add the address features as an attribute or inner class of PERSON.  If a person can have more than one address, then you have to reflect that in your object diagram.  Again, a disconnect between OO and relational.  In other words:  PERSON 1 => 1..* ADDRESS.

Comment: At what point, logically, would you want to have an address without a person associated?  You wouldn't.  Do you want to allow multiple addresses for a given person?  If not, then slap all of these fields into the same table and be done - that's essentially what you're saying: that you have to have both a person and an address, so why separate them if you're not going to a) allow multiple, or b) allow zero?

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Your reasoning makes perfect sense. Could you please convert that to an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At what point, logically, would you want to have an address without a person associated? You wouldn't. Do you want to allow multiple addresses for a given person? If not, then slap all of these fields into the same table and be done - that's essentially what you're saying: that you have to have both a person and an address, so why separate them if you're not going to a) allow multiple, or b) allow zero?  Putting them into the same table, in this scenario, is 3rd Normal Form, and is adequate to most uses.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your table schema, you have two options:

1. Only perform deletes via a stored procedure. Since this is storage logic, not business logic, it makes sense to encapsulate the deletion rules in a procedure.
2. Use an ON DELETE trigger. I personally don't like using triggers this way, but it is a possibility and would allow you to continue using EF unchanged.